# PySpark works in terminal but not when executed in Python code

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, avro, spark-avro

I am trying to read an avro file type. the following is the sample data source that I have found online to test my code:

https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/blob/master/samples/sample-data/avro/userdata1.avro

The following is my code (please assume that `source_path` is the path to the data linked above):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def avro_reader(source_path: str):

    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .master("yarn") \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
        .getOrCreate()

    reader = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(source_path)

    return reader.show()

print(avro_reader(source_path))
```

The following is the error that I am receiving:

```
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: hive.exec.dynamic.partition
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment.
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:631)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateSubmitArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1022)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1022)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Spark works perfectly fine when I run `pyspark` in the terminal. So, I am unsure what is causing this issue. Below is the output of running `pyspark` in terminal:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr  8 2021, 23:19:18) 
[Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
21/06/15 01:15:07 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.2
      /_/

Using Python version 3.8.2 (default, Apr  8 2021 23:19:18)
```

Following the recommendation to remove `.master("yarn")`, this is the error:

```
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: hive.exec.dynamic.partition
21/06/15 12:40:44 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 88, in <module>
    print(avro_reader('userdata1.avro'))
  File "main.py", line 26, in avro_reader
    reader = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(source_path)
  File "/Users/zaki.siyaji/Desktop/avro_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 204, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
  File "/Users/zaki.siyaji/Desktop/avro_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/zaki.siyaji/Desktop/avro_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/zaki.siyaji/Desktop/avro_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:692)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:746)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:265)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat.DefaultSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:666)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:666)
        at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:666)
        ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.master("yarn")` if you're running locally, and not on the YARN cluster. If you're running on the YARN cluster then you need to have environment setup correctly, and follow the [documentation on submitting to YARN](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html).

Update after new error message:

1. You need to change from `"com.databricks.spark.avro"` to `"avro"` as Avro now is supported by Spark itself.
2. And you need to submit the job with correct library attached ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/sql-data-sources-avro.html#content)):

```sh
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:<spark_version>
```

Comment: I removed the `.master("yarn")` function from my code, but the same error persisted. Any idea?

Comment: if it's the same error, then it wasn't removed. If it's another error - put it into the question

Comment: I have updated the question to display the new error